# How to pass data between wpf page and a window

Tags: c#, wpf, window

I'm developing a WPF and C# application and i have problems to pass data between a page and a window.

How is the best way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Check this out:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517214/windows-messaging-trapping-calls-originating-from-another-api][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517214/windows-messaging-trapping-calls-originating-from-another-api

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `delegate`event to do this.
For example in your MainWindow :

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Page1.onNameSend += Page1_onNameSend;
    }

    void Page1_onNameSend(string Name)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Name);
    }
}
}
```

And then in your Page1:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
public partial class Page1 : Page
{
    public delegate void SendName(string Name);

    public static event SendName onNameSend;

    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void SendButton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        onNameSend("Name to Send");
    }
}
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Such an event likely shouldn't be static; it should be an instance event.  There's also no real need to define a new delegate, just use `Action<string>` here.  You also should null check the event, so it doesn't throw a NRE if there are no handlers.  It's also odd to call it a "delegate event".  It's just an event.

Comment: You are absolutely right. But i just wanted to give him an idea or a starting point, so he can work with it.But every comment is welcome.

Comment: And all of the things that I mentioned would be easy enough to change for an intermediate or experienced developer, but not for a new developer.  As such (mostly the first and third points, the second isn't a "problem" so much as a stylistic change) not addressing these issues could result in serious problems down the road that readers may have a very tough time tracking down and fixing.  Leaving those issues there is highly irresponsible.

Comment: Couldnt agree more with you.

Comment: worked for me! I would like to see those changes @Servy

Answer (score -2):

I recently had this issue and was able to solve with public application properties. i do not know if this is the "best practice" in fact I doubt it but it can solve the issue.

```
//creating a new property
Application.Current.Properties["accessName"] = newPropertyValue;

//retrieving

RecievingWindowVariable = (castDataType)Application.Current.Properties["accessName"];
```